# Is it more efficient to create check constraints on PostgreSQL table before or after bulk load?

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints

I am creating a table in PostgreSQL and bulk load with data first. [PostgreSQL's documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/populate.html) recommends to insert large volumes of data first and then create indexes and foreign key constraints. What's about check constraints? Is it better to create them before inserting initial data or after? Or does it matter?

For example, a table will have an index on `time`, `NOT NULL` constraint on it, check constraint on time interval and possibly on `device`. If no bulk load, the definition will be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE conditions(
    time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    device int,
    value float,
    CONSTRAINT cond_time CHECK ("time" >= '2020-01-16 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone 
                            AND "time" < '2020-01-23 01:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone),
    CONSTRAINT cond_device CHECK (my_hash_function(device) >= 1073741823
                              AND my_hash_function(device) < 1075441823)
);
CREATE INDEX conditions_time_index ON conditions(time);
```

The index will be create after the bulk. The data to bulk load is cleaned and satisfies the constraints. The constraints are needed in future during normal operations.

Will it be more efficient if the check constraints and `NULL NOT` are created before bulk load or after? Does it matter if an index will exist on the column targeted in the check constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can benchmark it, but it shouldn't make a difference. The check expression will be evaluated for each row, and it only uses the data from that row. It should make no difference if that takes place while you load the data or afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So it sounds that there is no optimization for evaluating checks, e.g., using indexes. Then having checks from the start might be more efficient, since otherwise it will be necessary to re-read data.

Comment: A check constraint is only allowed to see the data from the row it checks. How could an index help with that?

Comment: If a check is only on one column, the index can show if all values satisfy the condition. It is unlikely to be implemented for check constraint, but it might be already implement for NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: There is such an optimization for `NOT NULL`, if I remember right, but not for check constraints.

Comment: Can you extend your answer with NOT NULL since it is part of the question? 
btw, do you know how much work is done to execute check constraints? Does PG store an internal representation of a check constraint to avoid re-parsing and type binding?

Comment: I mixed it up. I was thinking of [this](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=bbb96c3704c041d139181c6601e5bc770e045d26), but that's something different. The parsed check constraint is stored in `pg_constraint.conbin`. You'll have to test if you want to know numbers. The time it takes depends on the constraint.